# Conditionally overload an operator

Tags: c++, type-traits

I'm currently working on implementing some mathematical base operations and try to avoid using third party libraries as much as possible. I'm stuck at overloading the `operator*` for the multiplication of a `Scalar*Vector` and `Vector*Scalar`. The current code for the dot product of `Scalar*Vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<class Vector, class Scalar>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Scalar>::value, Vector>::type operator*
(
    const Scalar &a,
    const Vector &b
)
{
    return Vector
            (
                a*b[0],
                a*b[1],
                a*b[2]
            );
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<double> v1({1,2,3});
    const double s1(2);
    const auto result(s1*v1);
    std::cout<< result << std::endl;
}
```

The compiler error message is:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'const std::vector')
```

Any advises on how to overload the `*` operator, so that both dot-products are possible? I do not intend to implement these two operators in a custom vector class, as overloaded operators. Rather than that, I aim for the templated operator.

Comment: By the way, you're not allowed to overload operators when not at least one of the types is a user-defined, non-standard-library type.

Comment: You don't need to specify `Scalar = double`, it will never revert to what you give it; it will always deduce `Scalar` and `Vector` from the arguments you pass it.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Thanks, going to change that. It makes great sense, actually.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Vector will be a custom class in my application. Just for the sake of this example, I've used std::vector. I should change that....

Comment: After fixing unrelated errors, the code [works for me](https://ideone.com/5oQZql). (But the program is still ill-formed, see above.)

Comment: It is important to post code that actually generates the error message in question.

Comment: You might consider std::valarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a great explanation [here](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/11/a-simple-introduction-to-type-traits/) and used it to adjust it for the vector operations. In the vector class header file, you basically define via the `struct is_vector` that anything of type `T` is not a vector by default. In the following a all types that *can* act as a vector have to be listed explicitely, such as `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_vector
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct is_vector< std::vector >
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <class Vector>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_vector<Vector>::value, double>::type
operator*(const Vector &a, const Vector &b);
```

And in the executable, the code looks the same.

```
int main()
{
    const std::vector<double> v1({1,2,3});
    const double s1(2);
    const auto result(s1*v1);
    std::cout<< result << std::endl;
}
```